# MP3 player supporting continuing from the same time, or going forward or back in time within the same audio file

Tags: mp3-player

I listen to lectures on YouTube. These lectures can be up to 1 hour long. I use a YouTube to MP3 converter/downloader to get the MP3 file onto my PC. I am looking for an MP3 player supporting going forward or back in time within the same audio file, within the same lecture. I want that player to have buttons to move forward or backward an arbitrary amount of time. I do not want the buttons to skip to the next audio file instead. Or I want an MP3 player that can remember where it left off last time.

For example, I may be listening to a lecture on such an MP3 player. I have listened through maybe 1/3 of the entire lecture. Then I stop my listening session to do something else. When I come back the next time to continue my listening session, I want to listen to the rest of the lecture. I do not want to start all over again. It would be good for the MP3 player to remember where it left off, so that it can pick up again in the same place. Or alternatively there should be buttons to go forward, if I repeatedly tap the buttons I can get to the same place where I left off. These buttons shouldn't take me to the next lecture.

Since I will use this MP3 player for listening to lectures only, I do not want to have any extra features such as any wireless capabilities, such as Bluetooth, radio, or Wifi. I also do not want to have an integrated microphone. I do not want a very complicated device with extra features, or a device that could potentially spy on me. I do not want an MP3 player which is tightly bound to some proprietary service such as a music store, where one can play only audio files retrieved from that proprietary music store. I also do not want it to have advertisements or sponsored content. I want a simple device. I just want to be able to transfer the audio files of lectures from my computer, using a USB cable or a microSD card.